# Word cloud popup video

Tags: javascript, d3.js, video, popup

I just got the word cloud template from T3. Now I added a youtube link to every word in the word cloud, but I want the video pop up while I clicked the words in the word cloud. How should I modify my code? Thanks a lot.

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script>
var fill = d3.scale.category20();
var words = [{"text":"Worry", "url":"http://google.com/"},
         {"text":"Choices", "url":"http://bing.com/"},
       ]

var width = 1080;
var height = 500;
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
 words[i].size = 10 + Math.random() * 90;
}

d3.layout.cloud()
.size([width, height])
.words(words)
.padding(5)
.rotate(function() { return ~~ ((Math.random() * 6) - 3) * 30 + 8; })
.font("Impact")
.fontSize(function(d) { return d.size;})
.on("end", draw)
.start();

function draw(words) {
  d3.select("#word-cloud")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+ width/2 +","+ height/2 +")")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(words)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
    .style("font-family", "Impact")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
    .on("click", function (d, i){
    window.open(d.url, "_blank");
    });
}
```

Comment: So right now it's opening the URL in a new window, right?  If that's the case, rather than using the "window.open" code, I'd recommend looking into triggering a Modal Popup that contains the embedded video.

Answer (score 0):

My proposed approach:

1. Create a modal window
2. Open the modal when a word is clicked
3. Dynamically populate the embed code into the modal based on which word is clicked (I didn't do this part for you, but should be easily doable as it's part of the data to access).

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heybignick/5v3he9yb/) that gets you most of the way, with additional work needed here:

```
.on("click", function (d, i){
    // Dynamically populate embed

    // Open the modal
    document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
});
```